# Deleting a tracking branch in git

Tags: git, branch, tracking

I have created a tracking branch in git with the following command,

```
git checkout -t -b Bug_test
```

now when i run

```
$ git branch -lvv
  Bug_1515 8b4eec3 Changed product owners for required teams
* Bug_test c1fe1ad [master: ahead 1] Removed <members> tag from file
  master   af6df51 [origin/master] Merge branch 'master'
```

This is what I get, however, I want to delete the Bug_test branch now because I have no use for it anymore, can anyone advise me on how to delete it?

Comment: `git branch -d Bug_test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify -d option to delete a branch. The exact command to delete a branch in git is :-
git branch -d .

This means you can use following command to delete Bug_test branch,

```
git branch -d Bug_test
```

Answer (score 0):

save this page in your bookmark bar:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Basic+Git+commands

```
Delete the feature branch: git branch -d <branchname>
```